# Gtkmm : Color swap while drawing a line on drawing area

Tags: gtkmm

I am drawing a simple straight line on an image which is already drawn at the drawing area.

But at one unix machine, the drawn line in black color instead of red color.

Following is the piece of code to draw straight line:

```
Gdk::Color red("red");

//winPtr is type of Gtk::Window*    
Glib::RefPtr<Gdk::GC> gc = winPtr->get_window()->get_style()->get_white_gc();

gc->set_line_attributes ( 2, (Gdk::LineStyle)0, (Gdk::CapStyle)2, (Gdk::JoinStyle)1);
 Glib::RefPtr<Gdk::Visual> some_visual;
some_visual = Gdk::Visual::get_best();
Glib::RefPtr<Gdk::Colormap> some_colormap = Gdk::Colormap::create(some_visual, true);
some_colormap->alloc_color (red, false, true);
gc->set_colormap(some_colormap);
gc->set_foreground(red);

imgDispArea->get_window()->draw_line ( gc, 100, 100, 200, 200);
```

PS : -- Where "imgDispArea" is a type Gtk::DrawingArea*

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess here is that the problematic unix machine the X11 rgb.txt file is different. Per the [GdkColor](https://developer.gnome.org/gdk3/stable/gdk3-RGBA-Colors.html#gdk-rgba-parse) documentation:

> The string can either one of a large set of standard names (taken from the X11 rgb.txt file) or ...

My suggestion would be to specify the color as "#FF0000" rather than "red".